# Javascript Error : get(0).getContext('2d') Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, 2d

In this exercise I want to take screenshot of DIV. In this DIV **Google MAP** is shown.

To take screenshot I used this code,

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
        <button onclick="capture()">Click me</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function capture()
            {
                var c = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
                var t = c.getContext('2d');
                window.open('', c.toDataURL());
            }
        </script>
```

Some how it is not working,

**Throwing error - c.get is not a function**

If this not solution then please feel free to suggestions.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `get()`, it's for getting plain DOM nodes from jQuery objects, not for variables that are already referencing plain DOM nodes :

```
var c = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
window.open('', c.toDataURL());
```

Comment: Now its throwing c.getContext is not a function.Have I include jquery.min.js ?

Comment: Do you have a canvas with that ID, and did you place the script after the canvas in the DOM -> http://jsfiddle.net/S7G3Z/

Comment: @Napster - That's a DIV, not a **canvas**, it has no `getContext()`

Comment: As a sidenote, you probably can't do this as it's a Google Map, and you have no access to cross domain content, and I'm guessing the canvas is cross origin, coming from Google and all.

Comment: then what I do to take snap?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44132/discussion-between-napster-and-adeneo)

Comment: There's an option for getting screenshots in the Maps API I think, other than that, you can't do this.